# Rails Postgis Upgrade Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, homebrew, postgis, postgresql-9.2

I have installed Postgis and Postgresql through Homebrew on my Mac, and I wanted to upgrade my version of Postgis to 2.1.0-rc2. I unlinked my version of postgis, and then edited the postgis homebrew formula. After the new formula did not compile, I relinked the old formula and I now receive the following error whenever I try to invoke a database table with a spatial column:.

```
PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not load library 
"/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/lib/postgis-2.0.so":   
dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/lib/postgis-2.0.so, 10): Symbol not found: 
_json_tokener_errors
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/lib/postgis-2.0.so
Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libjson.0.dylib
in /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/lib/postgis-2.0.so
```

(I was not having this problem prior to doing the above action) I have restarted my postgresql server, and that did not work. I am unsure of what to do to solve this issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ah! Fixed the issue by reverting to an older version of json-c that homebrew had linked. (specifically json-c 0.10) it was as simple as the following command:

```
brew switch json-c 0.10
```

Hope someone else may find this useful in the future.

Comment: Never would have thought to do this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ultimately, I had to run pg_upgrade instructions as found here: http://blog.55minutes.com/2013/09/postgresql-93-brew-upgrade/

The problem was that when I ran `psql` it was 9.3.1, but the server was still 9.2.4.

Comment: Awesome! Brew somehow upgraded my json, rendering my postgis installation useless. So I had to upgrade, I thought, but even that failed, ultimately leading to this error, and this solution. Phew, lifesaver :)